# What can I use to breakdown an order of how many pallet qty case qty and eaches it used

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am analyzing orders  and I have the pallet, case, and each quantity.

The question is how do I get the total amount of how many pallet, cases, and eaches we shipped last year.

I am breaking it down by how many pallets, cases or eaches was used to fulfill the ship qty. I'm currently doing this manually and putting the values in three rows(pallet case and each) so at the bottom of the column I can total up the qty of pallets, case and eaches.

Attached some examples below.

Example 1:

Ship 50

Cases qty on a pallet 154

Case qty 5

Each ( we use eaches if the qty is less than a case) like if the customer orders less than case qty

Answer: we used 10 cases to fullfill this order because it was less than a pallet qty and it didn't have less than a case qty

Example 2:

Ship 2890

Cases on pallet 32

Case qty on a pallet 10

Each ( we use eaches if the qty is less than a case) like if the customer orders less than case qty

Answer: This order used 90 pallets and one case

Example 3:
Ship 9

Cases on pallet 78

Case qty on a pallet 25

Each ( we use eaches if the qty is less than a case) like if the customer orders less than case qty

Answer: This order used 9 eaches because it was less than case and pallet qty

[image: Sample data and template I am using]

Comment: Sum the columns?

Comment: @findwindow I want to sum the total of pallet case and eaches

Comment: Then sum that range or sum the subtotals of each column.

Comment: @findwindow Right but I my constraint is how can I automate the breakdowns of the ship qty

Comment: I guess each line is a different item hence different case quantity. You just do math depending on the item. This is something incredibly basic.

Comment: @findwindow for pallet I am using INT(ship qty / Pallet qty) and the case formula I used INT((ship qty -(Pallet answer * pallet data)/ case qty) but I'm struggling with creating a formula for eaches

Comment: Wouldn't that just be [ship qty] - [pallet answer] - [cases answer]? (And wouldn't the second example in the screenshot be 1 pallet, 1 case, 2 beaches?